# How to play audio alert in a webpage when I receive a specific $_GET value?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to build a website for water level sensing. So I want to play an audio alert when the water level is high. (http://localhost/waterlevel.php?level=HIGH). How could I do that?

Comment: You'll probably need javascript to do this. Or maybe you can include an audio tag inside of an IF statement related to your $_GET value, but I have a feeling it won't work on all browsers without user action. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this in any way related to Javascript?

Comment: @development-ninja It worked. However I tried to implement with this same logic before on Google Chrome. Now I tried it with Firefox. thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad to hear you solved this.

Answer (score 2):

I am quite not confident about this solution because not sure which kind of alert you will use.
But if you want to play sound alert without any dialog prompting, I suggest this.

```
<?php
  if($_GET["level"]="HIGH")
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
         const audio = new Audio('your audio url');
         audio.play();
       </script>";
  
?>
```

Comment: Note: I don't think this will work on any Chromium based browser (without the users explicit permission) due to it's autoplay restrictions. But that may be true for any answer.